# Generate checksum during archive file creation under bash

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, checksum

I want to generate the checksum of a file when an archive is created, rather that read the data twice.  Some of the backup archives are rather large.  The script is going on bash hosts so installing zsh isn't an option.  I have it working under zsh, but I am having trouble porting it for bash.

```
tar cf - folder | pigz -n > folder.tar.gz | md5sum | sed -e s/-/folder.tar.gz/g | tee sum.md5
```

Verify checksum

```
md5sum -c sum.md5
```

It works how I want under *zsh*, but when I execute it under *bash*:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  folder.tar.gz
folder.tar.gz: FAILED
md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

*md5sum* is receiving empty input, which is expected but not what I want it to do. ;)

Comment: I would guess Zsh automatically replicates output to pipe with `pigz -n > folder.tar.gz | md5sum`. Bash doesn't. Try starting md5sum as another command with folder.tar.gz as input.

Comment: ` tar -I 'pigz -n' -cf folder.tar.gz | md5sum ` is essentially the same with one less pipe. (capital i to specify the compression tool)

Answer (score 3):

The `pigz -n > folder.tar.gz | ...` part of the pipeline depends on zsh's [multios](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) feature to replicate the output from `pigz` to both folder.tar.gz and the rest of the pipeline. bash (and most other shells) don't have this feature, but you can replicate it with `tee`:

```
... | pigz -n | tee folder.tar.gz | ...
```

Comment: `tar -I 'pigz -n' -cf folder.tar.gz folder| md5sum | sed -e s/-/folder.tar.gz/g | tee sum2a.txt`
`md5sum -c sum2a.txt`
`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  folder.tar.gz`


...still yields the same empty input file under bash.

Comment: @Mpyusko That has the same problem as the original, `tar ... -cf folder.tar.gz` is sending output straight to folder.tar.gz, not to the pipe to `md5sum`. Try `tar -I 'pigz -n' -c folder | tee folder.tar.gz | md5sum ...`